# uiwebview Zoom in Not working perfectly

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, zooming

I have zoom my webview using the following code on the button click event
     [webView_ stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 5.0;"];

really the webview zoom when i am click that button after few second again webview comes normal state.
           Pls help me how to maintain that zoom without resize...

Thanks in advance,
     Suresh.M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your html document head

```
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=5.0'/>
```

Also, do

```
[webView_ setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

as iPhoneiPadDev stated, if you want the webview to also allow zooming to different zoom level

cheers

Answer (score 1):

try to use this.

```
[webView_ setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

This will help you.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Really I already selected the property of PageTofit. Normal zooming is working but [webView_ stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 5.0;"] this will work only one second after that it come to normal position. My question is I want this javascript zoom works permanently.